# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined (return promise?)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

```
firestore.collection("products").where("OrderNo", "==", inputx)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            var Nameout = doc.get("Name");
            var path = 'products/' + inputx + '-' + Nameout;

            tangRef = storageRef.child(path);

            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(function() {

                tangRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

                    document.querySelector('img1').src = url;

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            });

        }).then(function() {}).catch(function(error) {})

    })
```

I have referred to other solutions which have said about returning promise, but i have not understood what that means.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code in a consistent, readable way. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.) I've run it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ for you (no affiliation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` not returning `Promise` , it returns `undefined` implicitly

checkout this

```
firestore.collection("products").where("OrderNo", "==", inputx)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) 
        {
            var Nameout = doc.get("Name");
            var path = 'products/' + inputx + '-' + Nameout;

            tangRef = storageRef.child(path);

            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(function () {

                tangRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {

                    document.querySelector('img1').src = url;

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            });

        })

    })
```

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, so calling it always results in `undefined`.

You probably wanted [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
firestore.collection("products").where("OrderNo", "==", inputx)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        Promise.all(querySnapshot.map(function(doc) {                    // ***
            var Nameout = doc.get("Name");
            var path = 'products/' + inputx + '-' + Nameout;

            tangRef = storageRef.child(path);

            return firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(function() { // ***

                tangRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

                    document.querySelector('img1').src = url;

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            });

        }))                                                              // ***
        .then(function() {})
        .catch(function(error) {})
    })
```